# Matrix multiplication in python with classification

Tags: python, oop, matrix, multiplication

I'm new to here and I'm not really good at English so I apologize for probable future mistakes.

My teacher asked us to write this program with classification... Here is the code

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.mat = lst
        self.dim = (len(lst), len(lst[0]))
        self.rows=[lst[i][:] for i in range(self.dim[0])]
        self.columns=[[lst[i][j] for i in range(self.dim[0])] for j in range(self.dim[1])]
        
    def get(self,i,j):
        if (i) <= self.dim[0] and (j) <= self.dim[1]:
            return self.mat[i-1][j-1]
        else:
            print ("index not in matrix!")
            return None

    def __multList(self,list1,list2):
        if len(list1)==len(list2):
            return sum([list1[i]*list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))])

    def mult(self,other):
        matrix=[]
        for i in range(len(self.rows)):
            rows=[]
            for j in range(len(other.columns)):
                rows.append(self.__multList(other.columns[j],self.rows[i]))
            matrix.append(rows)
        return Matrix(matrix)
```

and this the driver:

```
from Matrixclass import Matrix

print("For first matrix enter number of row and column respectively: (Ex: 4 5)")

m,n = list(map(int,input().split()))

print("Enter Row values")

mat1 = []
 

for i in range(m) :
    print("Enter row",i + 1,"value:")

    row = list(map(int,input().split()))

    mat1.append(row)

print("For 2nd matrix enter number of row and column respectively: (Ex: 5 4)")

p,q = list(map(int,input().split()))

print("Enter Row wise values")

mat2 = []
 
for j in range(p) :
    print("Enter row",j + 1,"value:")

    row = list(map(int,input().split()))

    mat2.append(row)
    print("Matrix 1:",mat1)
    print("Matrix 2:",mat2)
    A = Matrix(mat1)
    B = Matrix(mat2)
    C=A.mult(B)
    print("The Multiplication of two Matrix:\n",C.mat)
```

And when i run it, i got this error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mult'
```

Update: Now it works; thanks

Comment: What values did you enter?  What part of the code did the error refer to?

Comment: **where did you get the error**? If you get an error, post the *full error message* including the *stack trace*, which tells us **exactly where the error is occuring**. Why would you omit this and make us guess? Help us help you.

Comment: In any case, your error is straightforward. `mat1 = []`. You have a `list` object. You then try to call `mult` on this list object: `mat3 = mat1.mult(mat2)` but as the error indicates, list objects have no `mult` attribute. Did you forget to create an instance of your `Matrix` class?

Comment: @ArjenSdq **don't post this in the comments**. Do you really expect people to read that? Please see [ask] and the [help]. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for help on formatting your code in Stack Overflow questions. Please don't be lazy and take the time to do things according to the rules of the site. In any case, I already addressed your error in my comment above.

Comment: How i can create instance of my matrix class?